# Can't find any WebRTC Native Android Development documentation

Tags: android, webrtc, webrtc-android

I am trying to build an android app where I have to intregate voice call feature. I want to use WebRTC for that because it's FREE. Now I have tried searching on the internet but could not found any proper instruction about native WebRTC Android. As per Google's [documentation](https://webrtc.googlesource.com/src/+/main/docs/native-code/android/index.md). I also followed [this](https://piranna.github.io/2021/04/23/How-to-build-WebRTC-for-Android-in-Ubuntu-21.04/)I have built my aar library from source code and imported on my project in Android Studio. But don't know what to do next :(

I want a documentation or instruction about WebRTC Android

Answer (score 0):

You can go through the below URL for WebRTC

URL:

1. https://webrtc.github.io/webrtc-org/native-code/android/
2. https://medium.com/@shivammaindola07/step-by-step-guide-to-build-webrtc-native-android-app-47898caa1594
3. https://myhexaville.com/category/webrtc/
4. https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/webrtc-web/#0
5. https://vivekc.xyz/getting-started-with-webrtc-for-android-daab1e268ff4

In this above link you can find required lib, pre-requisite software, sample application code and its documentation.

Comment: That's not updated documentation. It's not clear about the android library

Comment: @MdAhsanKabir I have added more links that will be helpful to you. please go through that